# How to count unit quantity in a certain polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have two shapefiles:

1. List item household units in each building in the whole city(green color building);
2. List item Polygons in the whole city(red color polygons);

There are 1 million buildings and 1000 polygons in the city.

How to count the unit in the certain polygons?

[image]

Comment: Are you comfortable using Spatialite and SQL at all? This would provide the simplest solution

Answer (score 3):

One option:

If a plugin is allowed, I would recommend [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin. 
When the plugin is installed, it will add `Reference`-group functions to the `Field calculator`.

[image]

Then,

1. Open attribute table of your city block (**red** polygon) layer.
2. Create a new field (e.g. `count`)
3. Give an expression `intersecting_geom_count('buildings')`... If your (**green**) buildings layer's name is *buildings*.
4. Click on `[OK]`

It will return number of buildings. (In the image below, `id` represents each red polygon).

[image]

NB. If any of the building is huge and astride two or more blocks, it will be counted twice or more.